# What does it mean in Go when you call a struct with (nil) argument?

Tags: go

I'm a Go newbie.
I have the following Go code (in the Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/A9d-GtHTNMx)).

I'm confused because I don't understand whats going on in line #17.
What does it mean to call `myStruct` with a nil argument as if it were a function?
And what does the `[]*` in front of the function name do?

I want to be able to compare `a` and `b` directly, but they are of different types.

```
 1:     package main
 2: 
 3:     import (
 4:         "fmt"
 5:         "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
 6:     )
 7: 
 8:     type myStruct struct {
 9:         e   protoimpl.MessageState
10:     }
11: 
12:     func myFunc() (*myStruct) {
13:         return new(myStruct)
14:     }
15: 
16:     func main() {
17:         a := []*myStruct(nil)
18:         fmt.Println("a = ", a)
19:         b := myFunc()
20:         fmt.Println("b = ", b)
21:     }
```

Output:

```
a =  []
b =  &{{{} [] [] <nil>}}
```

Comment: You can't call structs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type conversion. `nil` is converted to the type `[]*myStruct`, a slice of pointers to `myStruct`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't care for that syntax, as it just invites confusion. You can just use `var` instead, then not worry about having to do any conversion:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type date struct { year int }

func main() {
   {
      d := []*date(nil)
      fmt.Println(d) // []
   }
   {
      var d []*date
      fmt.Println(d) // []
   }
}
```